# How to solve non-linear mathematical equation in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I've two equations as:

```
x = c1 - y;

y = c2*c3*x / (1+c3*x);
```

where `c1`, `c2` and `c3` are constants. How to solve these equations in MATLAB? Please help.

Comment: You don't need Matlab. An analytical solution exists (although may be complex-valued). The only reason to use Matlab would be if this is homework, in which case you are unlikely to get help here if you don't provide evidence that you have at least attempted to solve the problem yourself.

Comment: @Colin, would you help me in analytical solution?

Comment: Apply quadratic formula to `ay^2 - y(1 - bc - ac) + abc = 0` to get solutions for y. Note a = c1, b = c2 and c = c3 in your notation. Also, be warned, I'm running out the door, so I scribbled this in about 15 second. I might have made a mistake :-)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs to: http://math.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I'm in a good mood this morning:

```
x = c1 - y;
y = c2*c3*x / (1+c3*x);
```

Now, pen and paper:

```
y = c1 - x
c1 - x = c2*c3*x / (1 + c3*x)
(c1 - x) * (1 + c3*x) = (c2 * c3 * x)
(c1 - x) * (1 + c3*x) - c2*c3*x = 0
```

You should be able to use [`fzero`](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/fzero.html) or [`roots`](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/roots.html) to solve this by yourself.